# Extracting childNodes from Table.getProperties('childNodes/children')

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

so I'm having this issue trying to scrape a web-table. Im able to extract tablenodes by using the 'firstChild' and 'lastElementChild' as a single child node. My problem here is that i want to extract all the childnodes(rows/cells) in map or array so i can iterate and extract data in a loop.

NOTE: im using puppeteer therefore ASYNC function

here is a code-snippet:

```
const [table] = await page.$x(xpath);

const tbody = await table.getProperty('lastElementChild'); //<-- in this case tbody is lastchild

const rows = Array.from(await tbody.getProperties('childNodes'));  // <-- LINE OF THE PROBLEM
const cell = await rows.getProperty('firstChild') // <-- using firstChild for testing (ideally 'childNodes' with forEach())
const data  = await cell.getProperty('innerText');
const txt = await data.jsonValue();
console.log(txt);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like you worked it out and thanks for sharing your solution as a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but for future reference I recommend including a snippet of the table's HTML or a live URL to reference in the question, so we know what's being scraped here. It's hard to suggest a solution without that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found another way...

here is the solution:

```
const row = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let row = document.querySelector('.fluid-table__row'); //<-- this refers to a HTML class
    let cells = [];
    row.childNodes.forEach(function(cell){
        cells.push(cell.textContent)
    })
    return cells;
  })
    console.log(row);
```